# how to undo transform using onMouseLeave React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an issue resetting the x and y values back to the initial values using `onMouseLeave`, I'm newish to coding. If any on could help that would be much appreciated.

```
import React from "react";

import "./item-card.styles.scss";
import Sneaker from "../../images/sneakers.png";

class CardItem extends React.Component {
  runAnimation(e) {
    console.log(e.target);

    let xAxis = (window.innerWidth / 2 - e.pageX) / 10;
    let yAxis = (window.innerHeight / 2 - e.pageY) / 10;
    e.target.style.transform = `rotateY(${xAxis}deg) rotateX(${yAxis}deg)`;
  }

  cancelAnimation() {
    // not sure what to put here to reset?
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div
          className="card"
          onMouseEnter={this.runAnimation}
          onMouseMove={this.runAnimation}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
        >
          <div className="sneaker">
            <div className="circle"></div>
            <img src={Sneaker} alt="sneaker" />
          </div>
          <div className="info">
            <h1 className="title">sneaker name</h1>
            <h3>something about a thing about something a day ago</h3>
            <div className="sizes">
              <button>8</button>
              <button className="active">9</button>
              <button>10</button>
              <button>11</button>
            </div>
            <div className="purchase">
              <button>purchase</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CardItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting `transform:none` style, we can reset the css transformation to default.
So update your onMouseLeave handler like below.

```
cancelAnimation(e) {
    e.target.style.transform = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Thank You, put me in the right direction!